# How to prevent docker java spring boot application exited after scheduled task completed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, scheduled-tasks

I have a Java Spring Boot Application which contains controller endpoints and a scheduled task. Scheduled task is scheduled for every midnight. I use docker-compose up -d for this application and it runs without issue.

However, after scheduled task completed docker image exited with code 1 and without any error log. I think docker thinks process is completed after scheduled task but since it is also used as a web application, it is not supposed to exit.

Is there anyway to prevent docker image exit after scheduled task completed?

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS MAVEN_BUILD
#FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD FOR JAVA 8

ARG SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE

MAINTAINER bugurs

COPY pom.xml /build/

COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/

RUN mvn clean install && mvn package -B -e

FROM openjdk:11-slim

#FROM openjdk:8-alpine FOR JAVA 8

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/*.jar /app/appdemo.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "appdemo.jar"]
```

Comment: A exit code of 1 usually indicates an error. Check your logs.

Comment: I checked using docker logs <service_name> command to see logs but only log is task is completed. There is no any kind of error log.

Answer (score 0):

if your app is springboot based then it wont exist using below dockerfile but if its simple java program then you have keep it alive may be infinite looping till process get kill signal .

Dockerfile

```
COPY ./startApp.sh .
RUN chmod a+x ./startApp.sh
```

startApp.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh
 java -jar ./appname.jar
```

Comment: I added the Dockerfile. Am I supposed to change anything?

Comment: Can you also provide how and where can I put an infinite loop?

Comment: Looping should be in you java code to keep alive your process  .

You can refer below blog ,here it is ending after "System.out.println" if you put that statement in infinite loop with sleep 5 so that it will  not end and keep running .
https://www.javatpoint.com/docker-java-example